# Selenium testing inputs

Tags: selenium

I am trying to make a test with Selenium to verify the exact number (and name) of inputs on a page. I need the test to be related to the xPath of the element (the CSS id), not the label. I've tried with *verifyAllFields()* and a regular expression but it doesn't work.
Can anyone provide some ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what flavor of Selenium you are using (Java, Ruby, C#) but here's a C# example:

```
private List<IWebElement> getAllFields(IWebDriver driver)
{
  List<IWebElement> fields = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@type='text'])).ToList();
  fields.AddRange(driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@type='password']")).ToList());
  fields.AddRange(driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//textarea")).ToList());

  return fields;
}
```

I know that you wanted the number but the reason you return the List of IWebElements is because you stated that you wanted the names of those elements and the count.  So if you have the object then you have the Text, Name, Count, etc..

Also there is a caveat to this.  When you find elements it will find both displayed and non-displayed elements so it might give you an invalid count but there is a simple LINQ that would resolve this depending on if you wanted only the displayed inputs.

```
fields.RemoveAll(i => !i.Displayed)
```

that statement right there will remove all input fields that are not displayed

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the CSS identifier of the input element you wish to count. You can use [this](http://www.eviltester.com/index.php/2010/03/13/a-simple-getcsscount-helper-method-for-use-with-selenium-rc/) function to retrieve the number of the input elements on the page.